# how to load image from src resized, or stretched

Tags: javascript, image, canvas, onload

I'm using fill() while drawing this image in my canvas. I load the image using the code below:

```
var cerceve = new Image();
if ($(".cerceve.accessory-selected").length) {
    cerceve.onload = function () {
        cerceveDeferred.resolve();
    };
    cerceve.src = $(".cerceve.accessory-selected:first img").attr("src");
```

Basically, I define the `src` of the `Image` object then when it loads I start drawing it on the screen. But I want the image to load in custom sizes, how can I do that? I cannot use resizing with `drawImage()`, because I need to use `fill()` method and it does not specify any resizing options.

For example, if I set `cerceve.height = 40;` after `cerceve` loads, it draws the image with a height of 40 (40 is bigger than the original height), but the source image is not stretched, instead it repeats, draws many of the same image. I give it a custom height and the image behaves with repeat option. I want it to stretch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I got it. Instead of trying to resize the source image after it loads, you should use context scaling while drawing the image on the canvas. `context.scale(x,y);` is probably the way to go.